# saving modified screens in python/pygame for later use

Tags: python, background, pygame, screen, sprite

When using python and pygame: after loading the screen with the background image and blitting new objects (Text, circles, rectangles, etc.), is there a way to save the modified screen so as to be recalled later in the program?  Specifically, I am setting the background and blitting new objects and would like to save the screen image with all of the blits in intact so it can be used later in the program as a new background upon which sprites can be manipulated.  Any suggestions welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

Blitting works both ways, meaning you can blit something onto the display screen, but you can also blit the screen onto another surface. So simply make a new surface the same size of your display surface and blit the screen onto that surface for later use.

Answer (score 0):

found a solution and it works better than I expected:

after blitted my raw background onto my surface and then adding numerous circles, rectangles and text to make an image with multiple dial, gauges and labels I ran the following:

```
pygame.display.update()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((800,480),0,32)
pygame.image.save(TFT,"screen_update.jpg")
```

the new image is saved to disk(XDcard on my RPi2) as "screen_update.jpg"
then I simply change the name to "ANAL_update.jpg" and use that as the background on my next program run.  I commented out all of the code used to create the rectangles, circles and labels and it works.  I will add an selectable "update" routine to the program and move all of extra drawing and labelling to that routine to be used when I wish to change the layout of he background.  I like the fact that the program creates a new updated file that just needs to be renamed for use and for copying the background to other machines.
note:  This is working on my RaspberryPi 2B with HDMI output to a 42" HD tv for development, but it is intended to run on an RPi3B with he official RPi 7 inch TFT display.  Thanks to all of you that responded and to the others who left pertinent code for previous questions similar to mine.